# NetworkBoundResource: Why `loadFromDb()` in `ApiEmptyResponse`

Tags: android, mvvm, repository

I saw in the [NetworkBoundResource.kt](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) source code from architecture-components-samples, line 90-97:

```
                is ApiEmptyResponse -> {
                    appExecutors.mainThread().execute {
                        // reload from disk whatever we had
                        result.addSource(loadFromDb()) { newData ->
                            setValue(Resource.success(newData))
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Any one have clue that why in the `ApiEmptyResponse` scenario, it reloads db and trying to dispatch a new db source instead of using the "latest" `dbSource` passed in the function parameters `private fun fetchFromNetwork(dbSource: LiveData<ResultType>) {...}`, just like `ApiErrorResponse` scenario.

Answer (score 0):

He describes it in the comment at the top

> reload from disk whatever we had

This used to ensure that you reload the lastest data you have and for sure to notify the live data.
if go and recheck the code, You will find a comment says:

> // we specially request a new live data,
>   // otherwise we will get immediately last cached value,
>   // which may not be updated with latest results received from network.

Comment: Hi Amjad, thanks for the commend.       Do you know why it didn't use the "last" `dbSource ` which will also notify the live data. Just like "ApiErrorResponse" scenario.           I can understand that it needs a reload in "ApiSuccessResponse" scenario, because the success response be saved in db, and the "last" `dbSource` is nolonger up-to-date. However, I don't understand why ApiEmptyResponse and ApiErrorResponse are handled differently?

Comment: If you keep using `dbSource` so you will have the latest data from this source not from DB, so he uses it in case there is another operation on this table.